# jquery drop down menu momentary blink

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a jquery/css drop down menu that I am working on for a website. It works well, except that when you navigate between sub-menu items, the selected main menu item changes it's text color for just a second because of the css border that I have used. This isn't very noticeable, but it has been bugging me for ages! I want to keep the border separating the submenus, but I don't want the flash! Is there some timer that I could use to fix this? Or could I make the border so that it is inside the box? Thank you so much for any help!

Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BLvKK/1/

note: I am aware that it would be more economical to use the css:hover property instead of triggering the rollovers through jquery, I just used jquery at this point because I was testing it out.

Here is the html:

```
<div id = "nav_div">
            <ul id="navigation">
                <li id="home">
                <a href="#" class="nav_style" id="home_a">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li id="sign_ups">
                <a href="#" class="nav_style" id="sign_ups_a">Sign-ups</a>
                <ul class="sub_nav_style" id="sign_ups_sub">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Camper Sign-up</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Junior Counselor Sign-up</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Counselor Sign-up</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li id="info">
                <a href="#" class="nav_style" id="info_a" name="info_a">Information</a>
                <ul class="sub_nav_style" id="info_sub">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Facts You Need</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Contact Information</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Vendor Information</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li id="about_camp">
                <a href="#" class="nav_style" id="about_camp_a" name="about_camp_a">About Camp</a>
                <ul class="sub_nav_style" id="about_camp_sub">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">What People Say</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Sample Menu</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Photos</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li id="donate">
                <a href="#" class="nav_style" id = "donate_a">Make a Donation</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

Here is the css:

```
ul{
margin:0 auto;
padding:0;
list-style-type:none;
}
a{
text-decoration:none;
}
#nav_div{
width:100%;
height:36px;
background:#b9bbbd;
text-align:center;
z-index:1;
}
ul#navigation{
text-align:center;
float:left;
}
ul#navigation li{
float:left;
min-width:170px;
font-size:13px;
}
ul.sub_nav_style {
position:absolute;
display:none;
padding-top: 10px;

}
ul.sub_nav_style li{
font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
clear:both;
background:#b9bbbd;
border-bottom:1px solid #999999;
}
ul.sub_nav_style li a{
color:#FFFFFF; 
}
a,
a:active,
a:visited {
display:block;
padding:10px;
}
.nav_style{
font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
font-size:13px;
background:#b9bbbd;
color:#FFFFFF;
}
.nav_style:hover{
font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
font-size:13px;
background:#114878;
color:#000000;
}
.nav_style_roll_off{
font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
font-size:13px;
background:#b9bbbd;
color:#114878;
}
.sub_nav_style_bround_roll{
background:#25313d;
}
```

Heres the JQuery:

```
// JavaScript Document
$(document).ready(function() {

    //sub rolls sign ups
    $("ul#navigation li#sign_ups ul li:eq(0) a").hover(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass("sub_nav_style_bround_roll");
        $("#sign_ups_a").toggleClass("nav_style_roll_off");
    });
    $("ul#navigation li#sign_ups ul li:eq(1) a").hover(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass("sub_nav_style_bround_roll");
        $("#sign_ups_a").toggleClass("nav_style_roll_off");
    });
    $("ul#navigation li#sign_ups ul li:eq(2) a").hover(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass("sub_nav_style_bround_roll");
        $("#sign_ups_a").toggleClass("nav_style_roll_off");
    });
    // sup rolls info
    $("ul#navigation li#info ul li:eq(0) a").hover(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass("sub_nav_style_bround_roll");
        $("#info_a").toggleClass("nav_style_roll_off");
    });
    $("ul#navigation li#info ul li:eq(1) a").hover(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass("sub_nav_style_bround_roll");
        $("#info_a").toggleClass("nav_style_roll_off");
    });
    $("ul#navigation li#info ul li:eq(2) a").hover(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass("sub_nav_style_bround_roll");
        $("#info_a").toggleClass("nav_style_roll_off");
    });
    //sub rolls about_camp
    $("ul#navigation li#about_camp ul li:eq(0) a").hover(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass("sub_nav_style_bround_roll");
        $("#about_camp_a").toggleClass("nav_style_roll_off");
    });
    $("ul#navigation li#about_camp ul li:eq(1) a").hover(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass("sub_nav_style_bround_roll");
        $("#about_camp_a").toggleClass("nav_style_roll_off");
    });
    $("ul#navigation li#about_camp ul li:eq(2) a").hover(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass("sub_nav_style_bround_roll");
        $("#about_camp_a").toggleClass("nav_style_roll_off");
    });
});
//slide toggles
$("#sign_ups").hover(function() {
    $("#sign_ups_sub").slideToggle('fast');
});
$("#info").hover(function() {
    $("#info_sub").slideToggle('fast');

});
$("#about_camp").hover(function() {
    $("#about_camp_sub").slideToggle('fast');
});
```

​
​
        ​

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want the text to remain white, just remove `.toggleClass("nav_style_roll_off");` from everywhere:

UPDATE:
To remove the blinking: http://jsfiddle.net/BLvKK/7/

Comment: thank you for your answer! However, I want the text in the main navigation to turn blue when you roll over the corresponding submenu.

Comment: Sorry, I hope I understood you now, if you wanted to remove the blinking effect/bug, the updated link does that. Hope this is what you needed